# Wifi router: standalone vs desktop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am upgrading my desktop computer (which is mainly used as a file/plex/torrent/video encoding/pihole server).  The motherboard I bought (Gigabyte Aorus Elite WIFI) comes with WIFI.  I am not sure why a motherboard needs WIFI.  Should I setup my desktop to be my wifi router instead of using my existing standalone one?

If yes, what is the recommended way to implement? OpenWRT?

I've never seen this done in an enterprise environment, they usually use cisco products so it makes me wonder if there is a reason why this should not be done.

Pros:

- Better Performance?
- Better Security?
- VPN capability

Cons:

- If computer fails, I lose my network
- Less secure? ethernet goes directly into computer instead of through another device.  I could sandbox ethernet to VM or setup on another computer
- Radio might be less powerful? though I might be able to buy another

Background:

My internet currently connects from my cable modem to a TPLink Archer C9 802.11ac router. My desktop computer is connected by gigabit ethernet to the router.  The desktop computer runs Windows 10.  I rarely use it interactively and mainly use it as a file/torrent/video encoding server.  I also have a ubuntu VM running pihole and plex.  My main computer is a Windows 10 laptop connected downstairs via wifi.  The main reason I run windows on the desktop is for easier file sharing connectivity.  Downstairs, I have a Tenda AC15 802.11ac bridged to the TPLink.  I have an HTPC and printer connected.  The HTPC acts as a backup server for the main desktop as well.  I recently got a ROKU which connects directly to the TPLink.  So I may decide to get rid of the HTPC, replace it with an old laptop and connect via wifi directly to the TPLink.  That only leaves the printer which I can figure out some wifi solution for as well.  So I may get rid of the secondary wifi accesspoint.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why I wouldn't do this, and a couple for:

## Reasons Against

1. As you stated, if you turn off your computer/it crashes, then you have no WiFi.
2. If you do not configure your firewalls and so on, you risk your computer. Normally your router is the first line of defence. And if you have your computer as the first device a hacker meets, and you don't know how to secure it properly, you are in trouble. Try looking at how many people are hacked by crypto miners, or people wanting a proxy to something like paedofile images and movies.
3. Your computer uses a lot more power than the router.
4. The hardware is not necessarily designed to remain on 24/7, so you might risk components failing before you would normally expect them to.

## And a reason it would be a good idea to have *a* computer as your router:

- if you know how to set up a server, you can effectively have a fully patched and maintained Device with current updates, instead of a router which doesn't receive updates 1 or two years after it has been released. My experience shows that many routers get a couple of updates, and then the manufacturer expects you to replace it, but the attackers also realise this, so any vulnerabilities in your router potentially means that you are vulnerable.

Comment: All good points.  However, my computer is on all the time anyways as it is acting as a server in my home so power and wear is the same.  In fact, not having the standalone router would save some power.  As for a crash, i don't know what is more reliable, my computer (more parts) or my router.  I suppose could just hookup my router again if my computer crashes or setup a secondary computer.  I do keep it fully patched and my router is 5yrs old and probably never has been patched.  Having the ethernet go into a VM or separate computer might help with sandboxing.  Is there a recommended solution?

Comment: Personally i wouldn't have a windows 10 as the router, but a linux box running endian or some other hardened distro like ubuntu core, or a windows server distro... I have had a server being hijacked by a crypto miner, where everyone says burn it and start over, so having my main machine as the router is something I would rarely be willing to do.

Comment: That is why I thought that putting it in a VM would help.  I do have a very old linux computer that I could use.  It's been sitting around collecting dust ever since I started using VMs.